# Get the Current Page Slug-Name

Tags: pages, slug

I want to Retrieve the Current Pagename , Inside my Breadcrumb , i tried many ways to get the idea work , but unfortunately they didn't work e.g :

```
           <?php wp_title('true'); ?>

           $pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
                if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {
                // If a static page is set as the front page, $pagename will not be set. Retrieve it from the queried object
                $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                $pagename = $post->post_name;
                }$slug = basename(get_query_var('pagename'));
```

for more Clearly Question , My Idea is to get the pagrname for the breadcrumb bootstrap , i mean lik this ' Home / PageName / Postname(if it navigated) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this from inside the Loop, you can get it this way:

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
```

Then just use `echo $page_slug;` in the location(s) you which to have it displayed.

For outside the loop, you will need to use different code:

```
$the_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
$slug = $the_page->post_name;
```

Comment: yeah i wanted it outside the loop . Thakns anyway man

Comment: Ok. Give me a second and I'll update with that code.

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: thanks for your Help , but the problem is when i enter to a specific post , it return to give the post name , not the page name .

actually i wanted it to be like this : Home / " here the code you added for Me " like PageName / "here the post name .

Comment: Page Name and Post Name are the same thing.